# EditText loses focus on Scroll in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, setfocus

I have a `RecyclerView` which have `EditText` as its list items. When i scroll the `RecyclerView`, the `EditText` loses focus when the item goes off screen. So the focus does not remain on the `EditText` when it comes back on the screen on scroll.

I want the focus to remain on the same item. For that i also tried storing `position` of the item on focus and reassigning the focus in `onBindViewHolder`. But that slow downs the scrolling.

I also tried this with `ListView` but there is another kind of `focus` related problem. Focus jumps there.

Have searched for this lot on SO and Googled a lot. but always found answers like `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` and `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` which does not work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The whole point of a `RecyclerView` is to reuse the views so that the phone doesn't have to keep all the rows in memory at once and doesn't have to be constantly destroying and creating views. When your `EditText` leaves the screen, the phone takes that view, resets its contents and moves it to the bottom of the incoming view stack.

[image: RecyclerView diagram]

This means that once your `EditText` leaves the screen it no longer exists. It cannot keep focus because it is removed from the layout.

The only way around this would be what you mentioned, which is storing the position, checking when that position comes onscreen, and manually restoring focus.

Comment: When there are 2 items (2 different viewholders) `RecyclerView` can clear focus on scroll even without calling `onBindViewHolder`, so we cannot set focus again. In this case we should use `onViewAttachedToWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Elan Hamburger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240139/2914140) wrote, we should store the position and restore it when an item appears on screen after scrolling.

A problem is we don't know when the item appears and disappears. When we have several `ViewHolder`s, `onBindViewHolder` can even not be invoked again. In this case we should use `onViewAttachedToWindow` and `onViewDetachedFromWindow` to learn when the item appears and disappears on screen.

```
private var focusPosition: Int = -1

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position)

    // Choose right ViewHolder and set focus event.
    holder.edit_text.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        focusPosition = position
    }
}

override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
    // Your condition, for instance, compare stored position or item id, or text value.
    if (holder.adapterPosition == focusPosition && holder is SomeViewHolder) {
        holder.edit_text.requestFocus()
    }
}

//override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: UinBillViewHolder) { //
//    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use the next:

```
LinearSnapHelper snapHelper  = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

It helped me when using GridLayoutManager with Vertical orientation.

This option scrolls the list a little on its own so that when scrolling, the edge of the next items in the RecyclerView becomes is visible, so the focus is not lost.

But this does not help if you need to scroll too quickly (if the column did not have time to load, and you need to scroll further).

I found the answer here [Scrolling recyclerview from the middle item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245862/scrolling-recyclerview-from-the-middle-item)