# Scrolling recyclerview from the middle item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scroll, android-tv

I am developing app for Android TV and I have a vertical RecyclerView, when I scroll the RecyclerView using the DPAD control the RecyclerView scroll down when I get to the last viewable item and then it scroll.

Is there away that the focused item will always stay in the center of the recyclerview while I scroll using the DPAD and only when I get to the last item of the recyclerview the focus will go until the last item.

It seems simple enough to have a build in option inside the RecyclerView but I can't find an answer!!!

Thanks!

Comment: you can put one layout(view) before RecyclerView in a required position make the view visible with the selected item displayed. I think there is no way to freeze certain cell and scroll in recycler view. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper) which can snap the item either vertically or horizontally. For example: attach the instance the the recyclerView like this:

```
LinearSnapHelper snapHelper  = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Here is more information:

https://blog.mindorks.com/using-snaphelper-in-recyclerview-fc616b6833e8

Comment: Doesen't seem to work on vertical recyclerview, the recyclerview just act normal

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed using a VerticalGridView

https://corochann.com/verticalgridfragment-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-19-718.html